# Replacing dialplan with ARI for "dynamic" inbound extensions

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

I'm experimenting with the [ARI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+15+ARI) interface in Asterisk (v15.5). I've managed to placing and manage outbound calls relatively well, and I'm now trying to tackle inbound calls.

I don't have any dialplan to speak of on my test server; it hasn't been needed: I just connect via ARI, [Originate](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+15+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk15ChannelsRESTAPI-originate) channels, and bridge them together. However, trying to send an inbound call to the server gives me an error

> chan_sip.c:26513 handle_request_invite: Call from 'upstreamserver' (192.168.x.x:5060) to extension '12345' rejected because extension not found in context 'default'.

Fair enough - Asterisk doesn't know about extension 12345 or what to do with it. I could, of course, add this into extensions.conf, put the extension into stasis and let my application deal with this: however, this has two downsides:

- We have potentially hundreds of inbound numbers, and we'd need to keep the dialplan up to date
- We'd like to have multiple ARI applications connecting to the server: it seems we need to specify a specific application name for each extension

Ideally, I'd like to use ARI to programatically tell Asterisk: *hey Asterisk, I'm an ARI application, let me know if there's any calls for extension 12345, and I'll take care of those for you*. Is there currently a way to do this, or is it back to editing the dialplan and pointing it to my app by hand?

Answer (score 0):

If you want control all via ARI you should do something like this

```
[default]
exten => _.,1,Noop(need ban this <${CHANNEL(recvip)}>);use fail2ban
exten => h,1,Hangup
[from-trunk]
exten => _.,1,Stasis()
exten => h,1,Hangup
```

You should not use default context in your peers/extensions

You also can use dynamic realtime and fastagi for control dialplan.

Comment: I get `Stasis app_name argument missing` - which means I'd need to hard-code the app name, and as per the OP I'd like to have this "dynamic" so we can have multiple apps connecting